# @TextIndexed in Spring/Maven?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

So I have been reading up on the `@TextIndexed` annotation and I don't seem to be able to include it with maven into my project. I am using `spring-data-mongodb` 1.5.0.M1 as per [here](http://spring.io/blog/2014/07/17/text-search-your-documents-with-spring-data-mongodb)

Anyone know why I can't use this annotation?

### Solution

In your properties, include 1.6.0.M1. I removed the version from the dependency bit. Then in `<properties></properties>` I put:

```
    <spring-data-mongodb.version>1.6.0.M1</spring-data-mongodb.version>
```

**Edit:**

As @Dave pointed out, you will need to include the spring milestone repository:

```
 <repositories> 
      <repository> 
           <id>spring-milestones</id> 
           <name>Spring Milestones</name>                   
           <url>repo.spring.io/milestone</url>; 
           <snapshots> 
                 <enabled>false</enabled> 
           </snapshots> 
       </repository> 
  </repositories>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to answer my own question on this one (kinda strange). So for anyone interested, some docs said that Text Indexing support for `spring-mongo-data` was released in 1.5 M1 +

This isn't true (at least on my system). It required 1.6 M1 +

I hope this helps someone out there, as I have spent a bit too much time figuring it out :)

Comment: Faced the same problem today. You saved me :)

Comment: So, could you please edit post with Maven dependency in your pom.xml?
I have tried to get <version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version> but it can't be found on central Maven repository?

Comment: Sure will do. Just letting you know though, you don't want `1.6.0.RELEASE`

Comment: To use this milestone you will also need to add the following repository to your pom: <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>